# CREATE_FAILED while creating CloudFormation stack from Hyperledger template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Following template guide from AWS on [Hyperledger Fabric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-hyperledger.html) creation:

Error which I recieved is ,

```
00:11:38 UTC+0550   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  hyperledger The following resource(s) failed to create: [FabricEC2CommonStack]. . Rollback requested by user.
00:11:38 UTC+0550   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  FabricEC2CommonStack    Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 1
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-1a328c93-6162-48d8-b84d-62dff9da3783
00:11:36 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  FabricEC2CommonStack    
00:11:32 UTC+0550   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  hyperledger User Initiated
```

Please suggest